# How can I align this text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, alignment, text-alignment

I appended values to a text file and I want to align it with the category on top, I have about 500 names and 10 categories so I cant do it line by line. I posted a small example on the bottom. I also want the first category to only have 23 characters max. This is what I did so far:

```
   fp = open(filename, "w")
   fp.write("Name                 Team Pos Games G A Pts PIM SOG Hits BS \n===========================================================\n")
   for items in stats:
          fp.write(str(items[0][:20])+ "  " + str(items[1]))
          fp.write('\n')
   fp.close()
```

This is the part I'm guessing I need to fix:

```
   fp.write(str(items[0][:23])+ "  " + str(items[1]))
```

Heres a snipit of the output I get:

```
Name                 Team
=========================
A.J. Greer  COL
Aaron Ekblad  FLA
Adam Clendening  CLS
Adam Cracknell  FA
Adam Erne  DET
Adam Gaudette  VAN
Adam Henrique  ANH
Adam Johnson  PIT
Adam Larsson  EDM
Adam Lowry  WPG
Adam McQuaid  FA
Adam Pelech  NYI
Adrian Kempe  LA
Alan Quine  CGY
Alec Martinez  LA
Aleksander Barkov  FLA
```

Comment: I was able to solve the issue with the format function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fp.write("%-21s%-4s" % (items[0],items[1]))
```

Tested with parse and reprint.

```
import re

TESTLINES = """A.J. Greer  COL
Aaron Ekblad  FLA
Adam Clendening  CLS
Adam Cracknell  FA
Adam Erne  DET
Adam Gaudette  VAN
Adam Henrique  ANH
Adam Johnson  PIT
Adam Larsson  EDM
Adam Lowry  WPG
Adam McQuaid  FA
Adam Pelech  NYI
Adrian Kempe  LA
Alan Quine  CGY
Alec Martinez  LA
Aleksander Barkov  FLA"""

print("Name                 Team")
print("=========================")
for line in TESTLINES.split("\n"):
   (name, team) = re.findall(r"^(.*?)\s+(\S+)$", line)[0]
   print("%-21s%-4s" % (name,team))
```

Comment: And yea, you can just add the \n to the end of format string and avoid the extra write call.